# Splunk: count by Id

Tags: splunk

I did a query in Splunk which looks like this:

```
source="/log/ABCDE/cABCDEFGH/ABCDE.log" doSomeTasks
```

I now want to count the entries in the logfile by `Id` (`Id` is an extracted field). But I only want to count every `Id` once and not every time when `doSomeTasks` is executed. How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count unique instances of field values, use the `distinct_count` or `dc` function.

```
source="/log/ABCDE/cABCDEFGH/ABCDE.log" doSomeTasks
| stats dc(Id) as IdCount
```